# I can't see leaflet drawing tools icon's pictures, why?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, leaflet

Please check out this website:
http://alfa-srv.geo2.pl/home

and login: admin@geo2.pl
password: a

then you see the place of the drawing tools but no pictures why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spreatsheet.pvg file was missing!